# Canonical question needed: simplification via user definitions

Tags: discussion, questions, site-organization

[Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) generously offered to lend his expert attention to the spectrum of problems linked from this Q&A:

- [Can I simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/121)

The full list of linked questions, 26 at the moment:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3822?lq=1

Daniel [requires](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136611/collecting-factors-of-polynomials/136656#comment369538_136656):

> It's difficult to come up with a one-size-fits-all for this. ... If you can come up with a canonical form of the question, I'll give it a try (next week; I'm traveling at the moment).

*I am requesting that the community examine these many related questions and jointly pen a canonical representative covering as many cases as may be done clearly and relatively concisely.*

This new canonical question should become the primary reference for this class of transformation and its answer(s) should provide methods that are easily applicable to a range of problems.  It is imperative that the question lend itself to this role and encourage this kind of answer.